# How to escape infinite loop in VBA / VB.NET

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, infinite-loop, halting-problem

bit of a stupid question, but I couldn't find any answers to it.
Sadly, I made a very shameful error, where I created an endless loop by accident.

```
Private Sub Textbox1_Change()
    Do While Len(Trim(Textbox1.Text)) > 4
       MsgBox "Please enter your birthyear in format of ####"
    Loop
End Sub
```

> As I wanted to enforce users to type only 4 digits, obviously not
>   realising I made an [infinite-loop](/questions/tagged/infinite-loop) given it's impossible to close
>   the `MsgBox`  as once you reach `>4` characters, it keeps on creating
>   new `MsgBox`es even after you QueryClose/OK the one that popped up.

[image]

Is there a way I could cancel it, without closing Excel altogether? Sadly, I can't even pause the code given the `MsgBox` opened in modal form and I can't click any of the editor elements.

[image]

Comment: @Error 1004: Avoiding a mistake is always a good idea, but your suggestion doesn't help at all, the problem is that the code is stuck because once entered, the condition never changes. OP asked how to break the execution, not how to check for a value

Comment: @Error1004 I actually did, but shortened the code for the sake of the question. Transformed it to a combined `if` with `and` it works now. Either way, still appreciate the effort to help out :) @FunThomas I think it's okay to leave it as a comment suggestion. The answers should be reserved for the subject matter, but I don't see it as an issue when it is in form of a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>.

This will interrupt your routine.

> *The <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> button is standardly located above the <kbd>PageUp</kbd> button on most keyboards*

Comment: I love you for this